# Can I get my question reopened, please?

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I have edited my question [Guide to Grand Canyon wildlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20489/guide-to-grand-canyon-wildlife) regarding a guide book for the Grand Canyon.

Could someone please take a look and reopen it if it is acceptable?

Comment: You probably should mention that you can't just click the reopen button yourself because you don't yet have sufficient rep.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Requests like this are probably better for the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) rather then Meta.  Meta is more for discussion of site issues and policies even though some are directed to individual questions.

Comment: @pnuts At one point you and I didn't have sufficient rep either.  20 rep to use the chat isn't that much.

Comment: @pnuts Yes but at the first site you did get 200 rep.